# Django multiple inheritance E005

Tags: python, django, django-models, multiple-inheritance, django-1.8

In the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#multiple-inheritance) it is stated that in order to use multiple inheritance one either has to

> use an explicit AutoField in the base models

or

> use a common ancestor to hold the AutoField

In my case I do have a common ancestor like in the following setup (as taken from the docs):

```
class Piece(models.Model):
    piece_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Article(Piece):
    pass

class Book(Piece):
    pass

class BookReview(Book, Article):
    pass
```

Unfortunately this results in the following error:

```
$ python manage.py check
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
testapp.BookReview: (models.E005) The field 'piece_ptr' from parent model 'testapp.book' clashes with the field 'piece_ptr' from parent model 'testapp.article'.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

Any way around this?

---

EDIT: Django version is 1.8.2

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that I can actually name the link to the parent:

```
class Piece(models.Model):
    pass

class Article(Piece):
    article_to_piece = models.OneToOneField(Piece, parent_link=True)

class Book(Piece):
    book_to_piece = models.OneToOneField(Piece, parent_link=True)

class BookReview(Book, Article):
    pass
```

I'm still curious for other solutions though!